# How to change a specific variable from data class in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a data class named "DATA" then I made an ArrayList variable like this:

```
    var listData : ArrayList<DATA>
```

but I need to change a variable in a certain position but I don't know how to change it. If in Java we can just use setter and getter. How to change a specific variable form data class?

Comment: can you show full code of the usage

Comment: `data` class in kotlin has setter/getter by default. If you want to change the value of an object, then you need to set variable property as `var`, not `val`.

Answer (score 1):

First (sorry I have to stay this) classes shouldn't be all caps :-) Usually, in naming conventions, this is applied to constant values. Classes are named with the first letter as capital only (just a recommendation if you are ever going to apply for pro android dev position.). Second, data classes are like much simpler Java's AutoValue generated objects. Their values are immutable on purpose. You can't change a value inside a data class. It is not possible in Kotlin. If there are changes needed in values inside data classes, they usually happen while mapping to another data class. Let's say when mapping a network deserialised data class object to domain layer data class object. (DataResponse -> Data). So if you need to change it, you can allocate the value of the data class to some local variable and then change it, or map it to another data class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to insert a new data in a specific position in the array?

Given you have your data class defined like this:

```
data class MyDataClass(var listData : ArrayList<Data>)

class Data
```

You just need to:

```
    val myDataClass = MyDataClass(arrayListOf())
    val someNewData = Data() 
    val index = 0
    myDataClass.listData[index] = someNewData
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
var dataObject = DATA();

dataObject.listData[index] = "Your data";
```